# I am not able to add media(images) in my WordPress post

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, multisite, wp-admin

I am trying to add an image to my post by clicking on 'Add Media'. The media selection view opens, When I select an image from the list of images, below is the error I get on my chrome console and the image never adds to the post.

[image]

1) I tried updating the `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` directory with the latest wordpress(4.9.8) version but it doesn't help.

- When I click on the '`admin-ajax.php`' link i get '0' as a response.

2) I tried updating the theme and the plugin but no success.

3) I tried in different browsers but just can't get it working.

4) I disabled the plugins and tried as well but nothing works.

can anyone please help solve the above issue.
**P.S. : I am not a wordpress developer.**

Comment: You should try to reinstall wordpress all together

Comment: Try clicking the "Reinstall Wordpress" button in the Updates area - you won't lose any of your content, plugins, or themes, as it only updates the core files. If you haven't tried disabling the theme, try that, and if you are using an ad-blocker, try turning that off as well. Failing all that, check the file permissions on your server and your .htaccess file - the .htaccess should have the standard default WordPress rules in there and sometimes it can get corrupted or worse, hacked. If you suspect hacking, try installing Wordfence or another security plugin and running a scan.

Comment: I think the problem is due to cache plugins (if you have any activated). Rather then reinstallation if you have cache plugins purge the cache and deactivate it and test. Hope this helps.

Comment: Try to inactivate all plugins, check your .htaccess and check also your file permissions via FTP

Comment: Something is preventing POST request to your admin-ajax endpoint. It could be either a security plugin or an .htaccess rule. As others have already suggested, try disabling all of your plugins and see if the issue persists. If it does, then have a look at the rules in your .htaccess file. If it doesn't, then it means one of your plugins is causing this.

Comment: Can we see the htaccess file? Do you have some caching enabled on your hosting? Do you use CDN?